# Plot paired data using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Is there a way to make a scatterplot in using seaborn where the (x, y) values are paired? I'd like the x-axis to represent values under condition A, and the y-axis to represent values under condition B. Concretely, suppose that x-axis is patient weight before treatment and y-axis is patient weight after treatment. My data is formatted like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'n': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
    'treatment': ['before', 'before', 'before', 'after', 'after', 'after'], 
    'weight': np.random.rand(6)})

   n treatment    weight
0  1    before  0.431438
1  2    before  0.053631
2  3    before  0.567058
3  1     after  0.324254
4  2     after  0.624151
5  3     after  0.519498
```

I think this qualifies as tidy data but the single variable I want to plot is weight. All the documentation I see for seaborn shows examples for paired data like plotting variable x of each item against variable y of each item. For example, sepal_length versus sepal_width. But how might I plot x versus y where my x and y are coming from the same column?

Is the solution to reformat my data so that I have a weight_before and a weight_after column? If so, can you provide the cleanest way to modify the data using pandas? I know I can do something like the following, but I feel like it's not great syntax.

```
df['weight_before'] = df['weight']
df.loc[df['treatment'] != 'before', 'weight_before'] = np.nan
# and similar for df['weight_after']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, this might work for you:

```
sns.lmplot(data=df.pivot(index='n', columns='treatment', values='weight'),
           x='before', y='after', fit_reg=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it

Pivot the dataframe;

```
df2=pd.pivot_table(df, index='n',columns='treatment', values='weight', aggfunc=np.sum)


df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Plot Scatter

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="before", y="after",data=df2)
```

Chained solution

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="before", y="after",data=pd.pivot_table(df, index='n',columns='treatment', values='weight', aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index(drop=True))
```